# Display attached pdf in browser within iframe - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have module which had a attachments functionality which uploads pdf files.
I need to display stored pdf in the app within the browser/iframe and without downloading it. Is there a gem or chance which will show/read pdfs in rails.

Note : The pdfs will contain images,text content etc.

Thanks in advance

Ranjit

Comment: Try this to open in browser <a href="http://localhost:3000<%= pdf_file.pdf_document.url %>" target="new">See pdf file</a> and you can read/show pdf files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, there is a gem is named Prawn in github. [Check](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/Using-Prawn-in-Rails-3) it out.

But there is more flexible way to implement this feature with Google Docs. You can embed your pdf with google docs viewer.

Simply:

```
<a href="https://docs.google.com/gview?url={YOUR_PDF_URL}&embedded=true">Your Pdf Viewer</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

In the 'show.hmtl.erb'

```
<iframe src=<%= @certificate.certificate_pdf %> width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"> </iframe>
```

just put the embedded ruby of the file as the source worked for me after hours and hours of searching.  'certificate' is my model, and 'certificate_pdf' is my attachment file.

Answer (score 3):

In your controller define a function like the following:

```
def show_pdf
  pdf_filename = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp/my_pdf_doc.pdf")
  send_file(pdf_filename, :filename => "your_document.pdf", :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf")
end
```

In your environment config (developemnt.rb/production.rb)file :

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

The config modification enables the web server to send the file directly from the disk.

You can have a look at this question [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code to make mine work in the view (with the example object `@person`) using the most current [Google Docs embedded pdf code specifications](https://docs.google.com/viewer):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.mysite.com/<%= @person.pdf.url %>&embedded=true" 
width="100%" height="800" >
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example PDF iframe:**

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

**Simply change xyz.pdf to the desired filename:**

```
<% url = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path("xyz.pdf")}" %>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<%= url %>&embedded=true" style="width:1170px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**You may also need to add you asset path if you haven't already (in application.rb):**

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<%= u @model.modeldoc %>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

The "u" is a ruby method that turns that makes the url URL-encoded (which google doc viewer requires). This was the issue I was having with CodeBiker's answer.

more info on "u" -- http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util%3aurl_encode